# Use elementary matrix operations to replace non-zero entries to one.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a real matrix  of shape [,].
Use elementary matrix operations matrix multiplication and addition to replace non-zero entries of matrix  to value 1 i.e. after transformation resultant matrix  must be satisfying following two properties:

```
B[i,j] = 1 if A[i,j] != 0
B[i,j] = 0 if A[i,j] == 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What did you try?

Comment: Is there a reason that you suspect that there is a nice way to do this, or that doing this is even possible?

Comment: @Nurator, I was just using the above two conditions to solve the problem. But, in doing so I was thinking if there is another faster way of solving it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, just trying to solve it using linear operations.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve it with linear operations? How did you encounter this problem in the first place?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Matrix A just contains weights of a graph which I want to reduce to the adjacency matrix. But I want to do it using linear operations because of problem-specific constraints.

Comment: @abhi The operation you want to create is NOT linear, so it will be impossible to use linear operations to do it. What exactly are your constraints?

Comment: @Nurator, is it possible to solve above problem by addtional use of elementwise matrix product and/or inverse operator. I know using these operations bring non-linearity to the solution.